# Xtemplate if condition

Tags: php, templates, if-statement

I'm making some project not beginned by me witch uses Xtemplate ( http://www.phpxtemplate.org/HomePage )  system.

I need to use simple if statements inside some of templates like

```
if ( user.type = 1 ) { showSomething }
```

I'm checking documentation etc and I dont see anything like that. I know that idea of templateing, MVC views etc is to seperate php logic from views but I think some simple conditions are sometimes needed inside view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the PHP xtemplate forums:

> XTemplate is not a programming language, it is a search and replace
>   template engine. Try Smarty if you want conditionals, we come from a
>   different template metaphor altogether.
>
> Conditionals are for the PHP side of things. The only 'intelligence'
>   is using tag callbacks, otherwise it's just simple search and replace.

Source: http://forum.phpxtemplate.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9

Comment: So you're in trouble then if you need for example to select some multiple options from $_POST from combobox... I dont get that 'metaphor'